# I have a really confusing issue with checkboxes

Tags: forms, drupal, module, drupal-7, watchdog

I have a problem with the value that checkboxes returns to me:
first of all i start with that 2 variables:

```
 $blabla_severity_levels =
   variable_get('blabla_severity_levels', array());

 $blabla_severity_options = array();
```

then i make a for each for the watchdogs:

```
   foreach (watchdog_severity_levels() as $severity_numbers => $severity) {
       $blabla_severity_options[$severity_numbers] = check_plain(drupal_ucfirst($severity));
   }
```

then i generate the form:

```
$blabla_form['blabla_severity_levels'] = array(
      '#type'          => 'checkboxes',
      '#title'         => t('Type of log messages'),
      '#options'       => $blabla_severity_options,
      '#default_value' => array_values($blabla_severity_levels),
      '#required'      => TRUE,
    );
return system_settings_form($blabla_form);
```

and in my function i call it like:

```
$severity_levels = variable_get('blabla_severity_levels', array());
```

now if i make a `dpm($severity_levels)`
it gets me out an array with

```
error (String, 5 characters ) error
warning (String, 7 characters ) warning
emergency (Integer) 0
alert (Integer) 0
critical (Integer) 0
notice (Integer) 0
info (Integer) 0
debug (Integer) 0
```

but i am really needing is the blabla_severity_options which is:

```
error (String, 5 characters ) 3
warning (String, 7 characters ) 4
emergency (Integer) 0
alert (Integer) 0
critical (Integer) 0
notice (Integer) 0
info (Integer) 0
debug (Integer) 0
```

I want to save the values...... any ideas plz?? i really need help

Comment: What kind of data is stored in `blabla_severity_levels` variable?

Comment: $severity_levels = variable_get('blabla_severity_levels', array());    i think array?

Comment: With that instruction you are loading the value stored in variables table in the database. If this value is not set, the function variable_get() return the second argument received: an empty array in your case. Could you please look into the database and see what kind of data is stored? Alternatively, you can use Devel Module to see the value stored in the variables

Comment: the values is 0 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 7

Comment: Hoy are you inserting these values in the variable? I assume that variable should contain the indices of the watchdog severity levels that were selected in the module configuration form.

Comment: i cannot undertand wht did you mean?? this is all the code that refers to checkboxes...

Comment: i think:  $blabla_severity_levels =
   variable_get('blabla_severity_levels', array()); with that line and with that lines:  $blabla_form['blabla_severity_levels'] = array(
      '#type'          => 'checkboxes',
      '#title'         => t('Type of log messages'),
      '#options'       => $blabla_severity_options,
      '#default_value' => array_values($blabla_severity_levels),
      '#required'      => TRUE,
    );
return system_settings_form($blabla_form);   I insert the values if you can understand.